# Is there a tool for getting vector map data of any location for design purposes?

Tags: resource-recommendations, maps

I know of a few sites that offer map data of popular locations, many cities around the globe, but I haven't found any service which provides vector map data of all locations in a form I can use for design.

Right now when designing an ad with a map, I usually screenshot Google Maps, and if needed, trace that data. But in an environment where low-cost design needs to be done quickly, I'm looking for a viable way of getting that data in vector form quickly (without tracing) at any range (area scope) that I need.

**Is there a tool / service for getting vector map data of all mapped locations?**

Comment: I think this question is somewhat relevant [Google Map into an Illustrator SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089407/google-map-into-an-illustrator-svg). The user suggest using [Open Street Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/47.802/10.797).

Comment: You may get a better answer to this on [gis.se] – but then I may be totally wrong about this.

Comment: I have found this site to be quite useful.
http://nationalmap.gov/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few:

- [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) lets you download an svg image. It's buggy though, and you'll get an error message most of the time.
- [bbbike](http://extract.bbbike.org/) will also let you download svgs
- [mapwork](http://mapworks.xyz/)s lets you download svgs for european cities

Comment: Mapworks link results in a 403 (April 2021)